# Android 8 custom AppCompatTextView's getTextSize always return 0

Tags: textview, custom-view, android-8.0-oreo, text-size

Only happening with Android 8 I'm seeing an issue when getting the text size of the view.

```
public class AutoresizeTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
   ...
   public AutoresizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
    super(context, attributeSet, i);
    System.out.println(this.getTextSize())
  }
}
```

It always prints 0. This does not happens when using anything bellow Android 8

is there something extra we need to do to be able to get the text size ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In my view I also had this

```
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
 ..
}
```

Apparently with Android 8 this gets called even before the constructor and was messing around with my sizes